# How to let a Service stay alive even if the application is shut down via Taskmanager

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I have read so many stackoverflow threads regarding this issues, but nothing actually works. But somehow it must work, since WhatsApp for example keep displaying push notifications even if you shut it down via the app task manager.

When I use back pressing to close the app it is "closed" and I get notifications. But when I kill the app via the Taskmanager the Service is is not running anymore and does not start itself.

I've tried:

- Run as START_STICKY
- Run in other process via android:process=":procName"
- Create a BroadcastReceiver to restart the push service

But all fails when the app is killed via the app task manager.

How can this be solved? There MUST be a solution, otherwise WhatsApp wouldn't work, too.

Comment: Now try the [Foreground Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Types-of-services) or the [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)! BTW, you should be using Google (Firebase) Cloud Messaging or some other third party services. The obvious reason being that a custom implementation can get messy real quick and its a technical debt for early development.

Comment: "WhatsApp for example keep displaying push notifications even if you shut it down via the app task manager" -- it is very unlikely that WhatsApp is using a service for this. Most likely, they are using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: @CommonsWare food for thought, I've wondered this multiple times myself. How would one implement a near real-time push service for Android? Like a reverse engineered GCM replica. Is it not possible using the standard application framework? Does it need system level permissions to keep the service running unrestricted (and avoiding that foreground service notification)? The work manager has APIs for background processing but I don't think it's meant for such usage?

Comment: @ashu: "Does it need system level permissions to keep the service running unrestricted (and avoiding that foreground service notification)?" -- I don't know if I would use "permissions" as the term. But you have the right idea: basically, device manufacturers could set up what you are seeking, but ordinary apps installed by users really can't. "The work manager has APIs for background processing but I don't think it's meant for such usage?" -- correct, that is for occasional, possibly periodic, background tasks.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the sharing the insights.